# How can I avoid this solve this exception?

Tags: python, selenium, browser, automation

```
for a in range(0,500):
    driver.get("https://www.vype.com/vype-dfw-fan-poll-girls-track-runner-of-the-year")
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    vote = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='css-answer-span pds-answer-span'] 
    [contains(.,'Dymond Wiley, Duncanville')]")
    vote.click()
    button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@id,'pd-vote-button10551469')]")
    button.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    print("vote "+str(a))
```

Sometimes it gets stuck in third or forth loop.The error message is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="css-answer-span pds-answer-span">...</span> is not clickable at point (603, 7). Other element would receive the click: <span id="pds-answer10551469">...</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can induce java script executor to click on the element.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", vote)
```

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() this will reduce your time.

```
for a in range(0,500):
    driver.get("https://www.vype.com/vype-dfw-fan-poll-girls-track-runner-of-the-year")
    vote=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='css-answer-span pds-answer-span'][contains(.,'Dymond Wiley, Duncanville')]")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", vote)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@id,'pd-vote-button')]"))).click()
    print("vote "+str(a))
```

Import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```